# play framewoerk & scala Future(s) chain. make it more pretty

Tags: scala, playframework, future, ws-client

I use `WSClient` to make rest requests. Each request return some `Future`.

as result I need to make request **1** and get some data. Then I need to make request **2** with data from result of request **1**. Then I need to make request **3** with data from result of request **2**. and so on

in my code it's looks like

```
def wsChain(data: Data): Future[NewData] = {
    getOne(data).flatMap(data2 => {
      getTwo(data2).flatMap(data3 => {
        getThree(data3).flatMap(data4 => {
          getFour(data4).map(result => foo(result))
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

It's very primitive sample without any modification of responses and requests. but I think that even it is difficult to read.
I now about `Await` for `Future`, but it's anti-pattern

May be I can do this more pretty? Without **N** inner functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is precisely the kind of situation that Scala's `for`-comprehensions are designed to help. You can replace your code with the following:

```
def wsChain(data: Data): Future[NewData] = for {
  data2  <- getOne(data)
  data3  <- getTwo(data2)
  data4  <- getThree(data3)
  result <- getFour(data4)
} yield foo(result)
```

…and it will be desugared by the compiler to exactly the same thing. You can read more about `for`-comprehensions [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html), but in short, any time you find yourself with a long chain of `flatMap` calls (and maybe a `map` at the end), you should consider rewriting them as a `for`-comprehension, which makes your code more readable by collapsing the deep nesting.